# Using mod_proxy_ajp, how do I set "special" AJP attributes?

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy, ajp, mod-proxy-ajp

I have set up an *Apache Web Server 2.4* to act as a proxy for *Apache Tomcat 7*, communicating via the *AJP* protocol (*mod_proxy_ajp* on the Apache side and an AJP connector on the Tomcat side). Everything works great for basic functionality.

Now, I am looking to set some specific AJP attributes, but can't quite get it to work...

---

Looking at the *mod_proxy_ajp* page (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html), under the **Request Packet Structure** section, I see a listing of attributes. These attributes include the likes of **remote_user**, and **ssl_cert** (code values **0x03** and **0x07**, respectively). There is also an "everything else" attribute called **req_attribute** with code value **0x0A** that can be used to set any arbitrary attribute in an AJP request.

Further, on the same page, under the **Environment Variables** section, it states the following:

> Environment variables whose names have the prefix AJP_ are forwarded to the origin server as AJP request attributes (with the AJP_ prefix removed from the name of the key).

This seems straightforward enough, and indeed, I am easily able to set an arbitrary AJP attribute such as "doug-attribute" by setting an Apache environment variable called "AJP_doug-attribute", and assigning a relevant value. After doing such, I can analyze the traffic using Wireshark, and see the "doug-attribute" field show up in the dissected AJP block, prefixed with a hex value of 0x0A (the "req_attribute" type listed above). So far so good.

---

Now I want to try to set the **ssl_cert** attribute. In the same fashion, I set an environment variable called "AJP_ssl_cert". Doing so, it does show up in Wireshark, but with prefix code "0x0A". Further, my Java application that wants to read the "javax.servlet.request.x509certificate" does not find the certificate.

However, I also notice some other attributes in the Wireshark capture that *are* listed on the website, like **ssl_cipher** and **ssl_key_size**. But in the capture, they show up as "SSL-Cipher" and "SSL-Key-Size" (and have the appropriate "0x08" and "0x0B" prefix codes). So, I try setting the cert attribute again, this time as "SSL-Cert", but I get the same results as before.

To compare, I altered the Apache configuration to require client certificates, and then provided one in the browser when visiting the associated web page. At this point, I look at the Wireshark capture, and sure enough, there is now an attribute named "SSL-Cert", with code "0x07", and my web application in Tomcat is successfully able to find the certificate.

Is there any way that I can manually set the attributes listed on the mod_proxy_ajp page, or does the module handle them differently from other arbitrary request attributes (like "doug-attribute")? I feel like there must be something I am missing here.

---

As some background, the reason that I am trying to do this is that I have a configuration with multiple Apache web servers proxying each other, and then at the end, an Apache web server proxying to a Tomcat instance via AJP. All the Apache web servers use SSL and require client certificates. With just one Apache server, Tomcat can receive the user's certificate just fine without any special configuration on my part. However, with multiple, it ultimately receives the server certificate of the previous Apache proxy (set on that machine using the SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile directive).

What I am hoping to do is place the original user's certificate into the headers of the intermediate proxied requests, and then manually set that certificate in the AJP attributes at the back end so that the web application in Tomcat can read the certificate and use it to perform its authorization stuff (this part is already set in stone, otherwise I would just add the certificate as a header and make the Java app read the header).

EDIT: of course, if there is an easier way to accomplish passing the user's certificate through the proxy chain, I'd be more than happy to hear it! :)